# Binding to Handsontable height property causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in tests

Tags: angular, handsontable

I need to dynamically change the height of my handsontable in my angular component, but doing so throws the error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when I run my unit tests. How can I set the height without getting this error?

I am using angular 6 and jasmine. I need the height of the handsontable to be evaluated dynamically because I dynamically add and remove components from my parent component. I am not getting the error for the width property even though I am evaluating it the same way.

```
 <div>
  <hot-table
    hotId="searchResultsTableId"
    [width]="getTableWidth()"
    [height]="getTableHeight()"
    [data]="data"
  >
  </hot-table>
 </div>
```

And in my component's typescript file:

```
getTableHeight(): number {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(this.element, 'height')
  const containerHeight = Number(style['height'].split('p')[0])
  return containerHeight - 120
}
getTableWidth(): number {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(this.element, 'width')
  const containerWidth = Number(style['width'].split('p')[0])
  return containerWidth - 50
}
```

My spec file looks like:

```
describe('SearchResultsComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchResultsComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchResultsComponent>

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchResultsComponent],
      imports: [
        HotTableModule.forRoot(),
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: SearchService, useClass: MockSearchService },
      ]
    }).compileComponents()
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchResultsComponent)
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })
  describe('processResults', () => {
    it('should pass the test', () => {
      expect(true).toEqual(true)
    })
  })
})
```

I get the error "Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'height: -101'. Current value: 'height: -43.734399999999994'" while running my test, and this only appeared after binding to the height property like this. I expect the test to pass without this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div>
  <hot-table
    hotId="searchResultsTableId"
    [width]="tableWidth"
    [height]="tableHeight"
    [data]="data"
  >
  </hot-table>
 </div>
```

And in your component's typescript file:

```
tableHeight: Number;
tableWidth: Number;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.computeTableHeight();
  this.computeTableWidth();
}

computeTableHeight(): number {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(this.element, 'height');
  const containerHeight = Number(style['height'].split('p')[0]);
  this.tableHeight = containerHeight - 120;
}
computeTableWidth(): number {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(this.element, 'width');
  const containerWidth = Number(style['width'].split('p')[0]);
  this.tableWidth = containerWidth - 50;
}
```

Explanation: Angular doesn't allow a property to change at rendering phase, because it would cause a sort of circular dependency:

- Angular is rendering the page, then checking the dynamic values
- A dynamic value depends on the rendered page

The `AfterViewInit` interface allows to execute code in a particular lifecycle hook, designed for this kind of use cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still threw an error, although you were right about needing to bind to properties and not functions. Angular didn't like that I was changing the view in a lifecycle hook. I got it to work by initializing the properties in ngOnInit. I also included an event handler which checked when there was a resizing event and then reevaluated the height and width properties at that time. This resolved the issue.